# Python 2.7 - find combinations of numbers in a list that add to another number

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

What I'm looking to do is find a way that I can have my code return all the combinations of values from a list that add to a variable, returning each answer as a list. For instance,

```
    target_number = 8
    usingnumbers =  [1, 2, 4, 8]
    returns:
    [8]
    [4, 4]
    [4, 2, 2]
    [4, 2, 1, 1]
    [4, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And so on. I'd like repeated values to be discarded, for instance [4, 2, 2], [2, 4, 2], [2, 2, 4] are all technically valid, but I'd like just one of these to be shown. Ideally, I'd want the code to also return the number of times each number appears in each list, but I'm sure I can do that for myself.

Comment: First tell us what you tried, what the result was, and what problem you faced that couldn't be solved by asking your professor/colleagues/Google.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Ah, thank you. My mistake, and I'll remember your advise in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In psuedocode:

1. subract the largest number from you list from your composed number,keep track of the number you started with
2. loop that until you can't anymore
3. move on to second largest etc
4. start this cycle again, but start with the number smaller than the last loop you did.

Not that difficult.

Comment: Thank you, this is fantastic. I should be perfectly fine programming this for myself as it was the theory more than the code that I was struggling with this time. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Not going to write code for you, but there is main idea:

Function `F(n, (k1, k2, .. km))` - returns set of lists of numbers:

`{(a11, ... a1i), (a21, ... a2i), ... (aj1, ... aji )}`

There is recurrent relationship:

```
F(n, (k1, k2, .., km)) = union(
  (k1) (+) F(n - k1, (k1, k2, ... km)),
  (k2) (+) F(n - k2, (k2, k3, ... km)),
  ...
  (km) (+) F(n - km, (km))
)
```

Operation `a (+) b` is 'append `a` to each item of `b`'.

There is a few of many corner cases, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete solution to the problem, the whole function is a big generator in disguise, the first `for` loop uses the smallest coin and in the second one, the smallest coin is discarded and the next big one is going to be the basis of our recursive function. If sum of current coins is equal to given number the list containing the coins is returned, if the sum is bigger then the number that list is discarded.

```
def changes(number, coins_available, coins_current):
    if sum(coins_current) == number:
        yield coins_current
    elif sum(coins_current) > number:
        pass
    elif coins_available == []:
        pass
    else:
        for c in changes(number, coins_available[:], coins_current + [coins_available[0]]):
            yield c
        for c in changes(number, coins_available[1:], coins_current):
            yield c

n = 40
coins = [1,2,5,10,20,50,100]

solutions = [sol for sol in changes(n, coins, [])]

for sol in solutions:
    print sol

print 'least coins used solution:', min(solutions, key=len)
print 'number of solutions', len(solutions)
```